# Angular Dynamic Path Parameter as Resolve Parameter

Tags: angularjs, parameters, path, resolve, route-provider

I have the following link in the routeProvider chain. What I want to do is reference the dynamic variable in the path as a parameter to the resolve function. Is this possible? Or would I really have to use $route.current.params.code when the parameter is referenced just above? And if you think I should use $route, how do I pass it in? Can I even do that here?

```
when('/subscribe-staff/:code', {
  templateUrl: '/build/modules/subscribe-staff.html',
  controller: 'SubscribeStaff',
  controllerAs: 'sub',
  resolve: {
    invitation: function (InvitesService) {
      return InvitesService.getStaffInvites(code)
    }
  }
}).
```

Answer (score 0):

My main issue when trying to figure this out was where to pass in $route, and also I think it is weird that we can't use that same variable pathname. Hopefully newer versions of angular can simplify this. For anyone who faces the same problem, you only have to pass $route in here as a param to your resolve function, and not to the actual $routeProvider setup at the top of the file. In fact if you do that, I'm pretty sure it will break.

```
resolve: {
  invitation: function (InvitesService, $route) {
    return InvitesService.getStaffInvites($route.current.params.code)
  }
}
```